# get year from string in format dd-mm-yyyy -sql server

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-server-ce

I am storing date in format "dd-mm-yyyy" as a "varchar" type in SQL server compact edition. I would like to retrieve the "yyyy" part which i will use to group the records in database. I tried converting it to a datettime format which results in a error "date or time part is not valid".

Comment: can you update the question with the code you tried?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: I found the article greatly enlightening. I wouldn't store date as string anymore. Thank you for directing me towards best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)** instead:

```
select substring(fieldName, 6, 10) from table
```

Alternately

```
SELECT Year(CAST(fieldName as datetime) as DateField) from Table
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Great Thanks. I used "substring" function to get year. "Year" function is not supported in SQL server compact edition i suppose. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
select year(Convert(datetime,fieldName,103)) as MyYearResult
```

This will more Helpful!!!!

Comment: SQL Server compact edition doesn't support "YEAR" function i reckon. It gives me an error.